# MySQL last_insert_id( ) returns 0 within the proper transaction

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I have a Spring bean that:

- inserts rows into a MySQL 5.6.12 table using JdbcTemplate
- retrieves the IDs of the inserted rows using the MySQL last_insert_id( ) function

The ID column is defined as `INT(10) UN AI PK`:

```java
@Repository @Transactional
public class UserDao
{
    @Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public User create( User u ) {

        String   sql  = "insert ...";
        Object[] args = new Object[] { ... };

        int mod = jdbcTemplate.update( sql, args );
        int key = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject( "select last_insert_id( )", Integer.class );

        ...

    }
}
```

The DB is an Amazon RDS instance. When I execute the given code from my Windows development box, **everything** is fine. When I deploy the same app, with the same connection string, pool configuration etc. on an Ubuntu EC2 instance, `last_insert_id( )` returns 0, **always**.

I've spent hours checking everything and I can state that the transaction is working properly, the insertion is fine etc. etc. Before tossing everything out of the window I replaced the `.update/.query` sequence with an `.update( PreparedStatementCreator, KeyHolder )` and... `keyHolder.getKey( ).intValue( )` works **fine** in both the environments...

I can't really understand what is the problem, if someone could shed some light...

*The software stack, just in case: spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE, bonecp-0.7.1.RELEASE, mysql-connector-java-5.1.25. Java 7 on both machines.*

Comment: Well.. this may be stupid suggestion, but I recently found a bug in MySQL so now I am checking everything twice. Although function names are case insensitive in MySQL, you say that you have no problem on Windows and it occures on Ubuntu. So could you try to use LAST_INSERT_ID() - upper case and no empty space between the quotes.

Comment: It's not stupid at all! Just tested, unfortunately it still returns 0 :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using:
    mysql_insert_id()

Comment: Unfortunately mysql_insert_id( ) has been deprecated and it is no longer available through the JDBC connector (but maybe it is still present in the PHP/C++ one). After all, I think that I will stick with the KeyHolder approach.